# Undefined variable in callback function

Tags: javascript, ajax, callback

I have an even listener on a text box which triggers the NASearch function.  I am utilizing a callback function so the ajax request should not run until after somevar3 is defined.  somevar3[i].data is showing as undefined when called inside the ajax function though.  Outside the ajax function somevar3[i].data is defined.

If i add async:false to the ajax function then everything runs great, but of course the UI suffers and I would like to avoid this.  Any direction would be greatly appreciated.

```js
function NASearch(query, callback) {
  var data2 = "{\r\n  \"ApiKey\": " + ak2 + "\r\n\r\n}";
  xhr33 = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr33.withCredentials = true;
  xhr33.addEventListener("readystatechange", function() {
    if (this.readyState === 4) {
      if (typeof callback == "function") {
        // apply() sets the meaning of "this" in the callback
        callback.apply(xhr33);
      }
      //alert(OrgLegalName + "2")
    }
  });
  xhr33.open("GET", "https://example.net/SmartSearch/NameAndAddressSearchAutoComplete?maxLength=31&clientAccountsOnly=True&accountPurposeTypeId=&institutionIdentityRecordId=&collectiveFundOnly=&query=" + query);
  xhr33.setRequestHeader("accept", "application/json");
  xhr33.setRequestHeader("x-api-key", ak2);
  xhr33.setRequestHeader("authorization", "Basic " + cheetauth);
  xhr33.setRequestHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
  xhr33.setRequestHeader("postman-token", "08c9199b-f6b4-22f1-bb8a-5d0dbdaffee0");
  xhr33.send(data2);
}

NASearch(btn.value,
  function() {
    //while (theultheb.firstChild) theultheb.removeChild(theultheb.firstChild);
    somevar3 = JSON.parse(xhr33.responseText).suggestions;
    console.log(JSON.parse(xhr33.responseText));
    //  console.log(SFaccountresponse);
    console.log(somevar3)
    for (var i = 0; i < somevar3.length; i++) {
      var identid = somevar3[i].data;
      var identval = somevar3[i].value;  
      console.log(somevar3[i].data);  //variable is defined here
      $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'https://example.com/Organizations/Detail/' + somevar3[i].data, 
        success: function() {
          console.log("EXISTS");
          console.log(somevar3[i].data);
        },
        error: function() {
          console.log("does not exist");
        },
        complete: function(xhr) {
          var xhrresp = xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Length');
          if (xhrresp == 44) {
            var link1b = document.createElement("a")
            link1b.href = "https://example.com/Individuals/Detail/" + somevar3[i].data;
            link1b.class = "k-link active";
            link1b.appendChild(document.createTextNode(somevar3[i].value)); //undefined here
            li1b = document.createElement("li");
            li1b.class = "listyle ellipsis-overflow";
            li1b.appendChild(link1b);
            ul1b.appendChild(li1b);
          } else {
            var link1b = document.createElement("a")
            link1b.href = "https://example.com/Organizations/Detail/" + somevar3[i].data; //undefined here
            link1b.class = "k-link active";
            link1b.appendChild(document.createTextNode(somevar3[i].value)); //undefined here 
            li1b = document.createElement("li");
            li1b.class = "listyle ellipsis-overflow";
            li1b.appendChild(link1b);
            ul1b.appendChild(li1b);
          }
        }
      });

    }
  }
);
```

Comment: When your callbacks run `i === somevar3.length`, so `somevar3[i]` is `undefined`. There are solutions in the linked duplicate.

Comment: Is your variable really called `somevar3`? You should give it a descriptive name so that you can still read your code in a couple weeks. Maybe you should call it `suggestions`.

Comment: I was able to solve my problem with the information in the linked duplicate.  @Paulpro i did update my variables to be more identifiable

Comment: Awesome, I'm glad it was helpful for you.